# Ignore index.php in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an app where every request gets sent through the index.php front controller. Pretty standard.

The admin interface will be loaded through `domain.com/admin`.
We want to put public assets for the admin area in a folder named `admin`.

The problem is when I add the folder, accessing the `/admin` URL results in it trying to load `domain.com/admin/index.php`

Is it possible to ignore the subfolder's index.php, or only allow js/css/image files to be served through the subfolder?

Or we could even put an index.php in there which somehow redirects to the root URL? I tried this but it resulted in an infinite redirect loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up just using a different folder name to serve assets.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may redefine `DirectoryIndex` to "forget" about `index.php`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

So now only `index.html` will be served if found, otherwise it will be `HTTP 404`

Comment: A 404 isn't really an improvement unfortunately. I want to be able to serve that URL through the root index.php

Comment: @Jason Varga: "A 404 isn't really an improvement unfortunately" --- please show where something in the question that should let us know 404 is not a solution. You think we're supermen here and can read your mind, but we (un)fortunately are not.

Comment: "The admin interface will be loaded through /admin". If its a 404 we wouldn't see an admin interface. Things could probably be rephrased, sure.

Comment: @JasonVarga well, `mod_rewrite` `/admin$` to some other page then.